# Returning value to Java program from Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing

### Background

I am writing this GUI as a plugin for another program. The GUI prompts the user to enter values which should be returned to the main program when the window closes (in this case the `println` statement in tester).

My current method is using an ActionListener on the `okButton`, which when clicked, sets `returnValue` to the text in the text field, and closes the window.

I have read through the docs and attempted to search terms such as "return value from GUI", "return field value after button press", but I have not yet found anything relating to my use case. I have minimal experience with Java GUI's, so there is a solid chance that I am  missing a built-in way of doing this.

### Driver class:

```java
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestWindow tw = new TestWindow();
        String ret = tw.run();
        System.out.println(ret);
    }
}
```

### Window Class

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestWindow {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("", 10);
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    String returnValue = "defaultValue";

    public TestWindow() {
        jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        textField.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
        okButton.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        okButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            // Set returnValue field to textField value
            returnValue = textField.getText();
            // Dispose of JFrame
            jFrame.dispose();
        });
        jFrame.add(textField);
        jFrame.add(okButton);
        jFrame.setLayout(null);
    }

    public String run() {
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        return textField.getText();
    }

}
```

When I step through the driver class with a debugger, the value returned is always "defaultValue", or the initial default value of `retValue`. Furthermore, the print statement after the `run` method runs immediately as the window appears, not after the GUI exits.

### Question

How can I give this value back to the main program when the OK button is clicked? (My actual program returns a hashmap of the various values set in the UI, but I have simplified it to a text field for purposes of a MCVE).

Edit with more context:
I am writing a plugin for MagicDraw. There is not an existing Swing UI that I can take advantage of. The user clicks a button in the MagicDraw UI, which launches my plugin. Originally the plugin used hard coded variables with no Swing UI, and this is an extension of that. However, from my understanding, my question should be agnostic of this.

Comment: Use a modal dialog, see [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use a modal dialog, see [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

As a simple example, you could just use `JOptionPane`...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.setText("Default value");
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Type something: "));
        contentPane.add(textField);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, contentPane, "Type someting", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println(textField.getText());
    }
});
```

The alternative would be to implement some kind of [observer pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which could be called when the `ActionListener` is triggered, but to be honest, a `JOptionPane` is just simpler

Comment: This looks close to what I'm needing. Just to confirm, is there a way to access that value from outside the scope of those braces, such as returning it? I am able to print it inside.

Comment: @blackbrandt That would depend on your needs.  Swing is single threaded and not thread safe, so all UI interactions should take place within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  A more complex solution might require some kind of "observer pattern", but that would require more context

Comment: @blackbrandt *"My actual program returns a hashmap of the various values set in the UI"* suggests that you are already running an existing Swing UI, so, assuming you're making the prompt from within the context of the EDT, then you can simply make use of modal dialog, without the additional `EventQueue` wrapper

Comment: I am writing a plugin for another program (Magicdraw). There is not an existing swing UI.

Comment: @blackbrandt MagicDraw is written Java? So it's using, what, AWT, Swing, JavaFX? I had a quick google and the [Writing plugins](https://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD185/Writing+plugins) seems to indicate support for Swing

Answer (score 0):

I propose writing a minimal interface for a callback, such as:

```
interface StuffToDoWithDialog {
    // will be called once values for foo and bar are ready
    void doStuff(String foo, int bar);
}
```

and building the interface so that, once values are ready, the passed-in instance of this interface is called:

```
public static void showDialog(StuffToDoWithDialog callback) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        // ... draw interface ...
        // ... and somewhere, once values are ready, call callback
        callback.doStuff(foo, bar);
    });
}
```

this makes it very simple to test, and you can pass in much more complex behavior when needed:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    showDialog((foo, bar) -> {
        System.out.println("Foo is " + foo);
        System.out.println("Bar is " + bar);
    });
}
```

Working program (save as `Example.java`):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {

    interface StuffToDoWithDialog {
        void doStuff(String foo, int bar);
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        showDialog((foo, bar) -> {
            System.out.println("Foo is " + foo);
            System.out.println("Bar is " + bar);
        });
    }

    private static JTextField addFormRowToPanel(JPanel panel, String label, int rowNum) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.ipadx = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = rowNum;
        panel.add(new JLabel(label), gbc);
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, (int)field.getPreferredSize().getHeight()));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(field, gbc);
        return field;
    }

    public static void showDialog(StuffToDoWithDialog callback) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            // builds contents for dialog: two inputs with labels
            JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JTextField foo = addFormRowToPanel(jp, "String foo", 0);
            JTextField bar = addFormRowToPanel(jp, "Integer bar", 1);
            
            boolean valid = false;
            while ( ! valid) {
                // blocks while showing dialog
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    jp, "Input options", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                // checks results
               if (foo.getText() != null 
                    && bar.getText() != null 
                    &&  bar.getText().matches("[0-9]+")) {
                        valid = true;
                } else {
                    // complain: bad inputs
                    int rc = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                        "Invalid inputs, try again or cancel?", "Error", 
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    if (rc == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) return;
                }
            }

            // returns results
            callback.doStuff(foo.getText(), Integer.parseInt(bar.getText()));
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: Or, you could just do the work on the EDT and make use of a dialog as a starting point :P

Comment: My point is the use of callbacks to decouple how-you-get-the-data with what-you-do-with-it, not where the code runs. Yes, the EDT is not where the work should be done, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Actually, I'd argue, that's the whole point the answer should be making (IMHO) - the code should be run within the EDT - obviously, more scope/context would be helpful, otherwise it's near impossible to answer the question. *"My actual program returns a hashmap of the various values set in the UI"* would suggest that they have an existing UI, which I assume is Swing, based on the available code, so the "simple" answer is "use a modal dialog"

Comment: Oh, and I'm all for delegation and observers, but only where I really need it 